# MATLAB function to output variable as delimited .txt

Tags: matlab

I want to write a `lazy mans` command to output any variable I choose in the workspace as a comma delimited `.txt` file. I know you can use `dlmwrite('outName.txt',varname);` but I want something where I can simply go `out(varname)` and it does the same thing.

So far I have come up with this:
First function needed toget the varname as a string name

```
function out = strfromvar(input)
    out = inputname(1);
end
```

Second function to `dlmwrite` that string name and variable...

```
function [out] = toigor(input)
    stringName = strfromvar(input);
    outName = [stringName '.txt'];
    dlmwrite(outName,input);
end
```

The area I am stuck is at the `outName` area. I cant get it so it turns my chosen variable into a `.txt` file. It just calls it 'input'. The file works as anticipated but i'd liek the program to fully work. I am sure I am just missing a small bit here.

Comment: The problem is that by the time you call your top function, your variable has already got the name `input`. This problem can be avoided by doing everything in 1 step.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to figure out why it kept defaulting to `input`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what does the trick for me:

```
function toigor(input)
    stringName = inputname(1);
    outName = [stringName '.txt'];
    dlmwrite(outName,input);
end
```

Note that you only need 1 function.

Comment: Thank you sir. This pleases me greatly.